# paged variable not working for category/custom post archive

Tags: wp-query, pagination, 404-error

I am having trouble getting the pagination to work on category archives for a custom post type.

The number of pages/links is accurate, but clicking on the link 404s. (Only in the category archive, pagination is working elsewhere in the site)

The URL is formatted like so: `http://domain.com/projects/category/category_name`

The Permalink structure is: `/%category%/%postname`

My loop is as follows (in the `archive-project.php` template for the custom post type `project`)

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

```
    $queryArgs = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged
    );

    if (isset($project_cat)) {
        $queryArgs = array_merge($queryArgs, array(
            'category_name' => $project_cat
        ));
    }
    $projectQuery = new WP_Query($queryArgs);
```

The second page is generated as `http://domain.com/projects/category/category_name/page/2` which returns a **404**.

The code for my pagination is as follows (Maybe it's not the best route, but it works on every other part of the site, after much headache as well)

```
global $projectQuery;

$total_pages = $projectQuery->max_num_pages;

if ($total_pages > 1){

  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

  echo paginate_links(array(
      'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
      'show_all' => true,
      'format' => '/page/%#%',
      'prev_next' => false,
      'current' => $current_page,
      'total' => $total_pages,
    ));
}
```

As mentioned, the page links appear to be accurate, but visiting the `Page 2` link gives a 404. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, I have spent hours on pagination alone, it is a surprisingly complex issue with Wordpress.

I've managed to narrow it down that the paged variable is not working properly here, `(get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` is always returning `0` although maybe it is due to the formatting of the link.

---

Additional quick notes:

`http://domain.com/projects/page/2` <-- Works
`http://domain.com/projects/category/category_name` <-- Works
`http://domain.com/projects/category/category_name/page/2` <-- 404

Reading Settings: `Blog pages show at most 1 posts`

Comment: try with re-flush permalinks settings, hope will solve your problem

Comment: why are you running a custom query instead of using the default main query?

Comment: also - `archive-project` is not the template WordPress will use for a taxonomy term archive, see the [Template Hierarchy for taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display).

Comment: @Milo - Thanks for your response, I am using a custom query to work with paging, affect the category and to allow the loop to function regularly on other archives/pages etc. Regarding your second comment, it is not a custom taxonomy, but a custom post type, so archive-project should be correct: (from the link you sent) `Custom Post Types display

Template file used to render the Archive Index page for a Custom Post Type

archive-{post_type}.php - If the post type were product, WordPress would look for archive-product.php.`

Comment: @Anjum - Unfortunately, flushing permalinks seems to have no effect.

Comment: @waffl - your question says "category archives for a custom post type", and your example URL that doesn't work appears to be for a taxonomy term. anyway, don't run a custom query, get rid of all that code, run the normal loop, use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to alter main queries *before* they're run- pagination problems solved.

Comment: @Milo - Thank you, I was trying to do this without a custom loop but found that I was then unable to have `category archives` within the `custom post type` archive. Without the custom `if (isset($project_cat))...`, I found that URLs such as `http://domain.com/post-type/category/category-name` were showing all of the `post-type` articles, and oddly enough, the category archive itself `http://domain.com/category/category-name` displays nothing. (no posts found)

Comment: @Milo - If you look at my edit on the top of the question, it seems oddly limited to the fact that the `paged` variable simply is not pulled in via the URL. Changing the `paged` variable in the loop itself works fine, but the URL does not - `http://domain.com/post-type/category/category-name/page/#` - only the `/page/#` isn't working for some reason... Actually, I have finally found that Wordpress, thinks the category is `category-name/page/2` - due to a [custom rewrite function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples) I had to insert

Comment: Why are you creating a brand new query? Use `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query, your code will be simpler, smaller, and faster! See the comment from @Milo

Comment: i think you can check this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193556/creating-a-custom-category-page-with-pagination

Comment: i think you should try like this :  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/304006/custom-loop-pagination-issue-pagination-not-showing-up?answertab=votes#tab-top . it's already working in my project.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try this?

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Comment: Also Can you change this line $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged')); by $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('page'));

Comment: For starters, you can [edit](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/156454/edit) your answers. That being said, an answer might not need to be a thorough solution - proofs of concept are valid as well - but they should be more than a hint of what an OP *could* try. Either this is what he or she *should* do to remedy the issue, or it isn't an answer...